How To Change Property of an Object with a function
I'm currently trying to change the property of my Book object, here's the code:
const myLibrary = [];
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
}

const harryPotter1 = new Book("Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone", 'J.K. Rowling', 309, 'No');
const harryPotter2 = new Book('Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets ', 'J.K. Rowling', 341, 'No');
const harryPotter3 = new Book("Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban", 'J.K. Rowling', 435, 'No');
const harryPotter4 = new Book("Harry Poter and The Goblet of Fire", "J.K. Rowling", 734, 'No');
const harryPotter5 = new Book("Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix", "J.K. Rowling", 870, 'No');

myLibrary.push(harryPotter1);
myLibrary.push(harryPotter2);
myLibrary.push(harryPotter3);
myLibrary.push(harryPotter4);
myLibrary.push(harryPotter5);

So I have a myLibrary array which consists of 5 Book objects, I'd like to change the property read at the click of a button.
Here's the code I wrote to display the books in the browser:
const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');

function createDeck() {
  
  
    while (deck.hasChildNodes()) {
        deck.removeChild(deck.firstChild)};
    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {

     
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    

myLibrary[i].index = i;//add index numbers property to every new book.

card.innerHTML = `<div class="card"">
<div class="title">${myLibrary[i].title}</div>
<div class="author">By ${myLibrary[i].author}</div>
<div class="pages">${myLibrary[i].pages} pages</div>
<div class="read">Read: ${myLibrary[i].read}</div>

<button class="delete" onclick="deleteItem(${myLibrary[i].index})">Delete Book</button>

//the button to change the read property of each book
<button class="changestatus" onclick="changeStatus(${myLibrary[i].read})">Change Status</button>


</div>`

deck.appendChild(card);

}
}



And here's the code to change the read property from "No" to "Yes", vice versa:
function changeStatus(status) {
      if (status === "Yes") {
        status = "No";
      }
      else if (status === "No") {
        status = "Yes";
        }
    };

I had hoped for when I clicked on the changeStatus button, each individual book object will change its read property. However, this is what I get when I clicked the changeStatus buttons of all the books.
index.html:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: No is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:52:51)
And I suppose the No in question is from the ${myLibrary[i].read} in this code:
<button class="changestatus" onclick="changeStatus(${myLibrary[i].read})">Change Status</button>
I'm stuck on how to fix this because I applied what I used on the deleteButton like so:
<button class="delete" onclick="deleteItem(${myLibrary[i].index})">Delete Book</button>

function deleteItem(cardIndex) {
    myLibrary.splice(cardIndex,1)

    while (deck.hasChildNodes()) {
        deck.removeChild(deck.firstChild);
    }
createDeck();
}

and the delete button worked fine..
Any inputs are appreciated. Thank you!

Don't pass changeStatus(${myLibrary[i].read}), pass changeStatus(${myLibrary[i]}). Then in the function, set book.read = 'Yes'. Though that won't work with your current code at all, the way you're generating HTML literals with just text values.

@deceze hi, I actually tried that too before i posted! This is what I got in the console:   index.html:52 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object' (at index.html:52:59),

Yeah, because you're trying to create HTML code, and you can't express an object reference by HTML. If you want to continue on this route, at best you can pass i as text in HTML, and then use that i value to look up the actual object from myLibrary[i] in the changeStatus function. — But more sanely, you should construct DOM objects using document.createElement(...) and use addEventListener to add a callback function in code; then you can pass anything you want and aren't restricted to what you can squeeze through HTML text.

I see.. Okay thank you so much!  I'll try working on it now.

@deceze ♦
Hey I just wanted to let you know that I took your advice and created my book objects using DOM objects and the changeStatus function now works! Thank you so much!
